# Type coercion fails when grabbing from an array

Tags: actionscript-3

Say I have a class `Person` with a private array called `children`, containing `Person` objects. It has a method `getChildren():Array { return this.children; }`.

If I do `trace(p.getChildren()[0])` (where `p` is an instance of `Person`), I can successfully print out whatever the first child is in the array. However, if I try to cast `var firstChild:Person = p.getChildren()[0]`, I get an error saying `Type Coercion failed: cannot convert []@a027b81 to classes.Person`.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Try `var firstChild:Person = p.getChildren()[0] as Person;`. Also you can try to check the type of that object that you have in that array - maybe it's something else :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov Ahh, in the end it was indeed a problem with how I added the children--I had something like `function addChildren(... args)` and just did `this.children.push(args);` inside, which apparently didn't work even though a `trace` made it look like it was completely fine.

Comment: Great that you've solved it :)

Comment: instead of `push` you can use `concat` ->   `this.children.concat(args)` should do what you're wanting (though this isn't really related to your question/error).

Comment: `contact` is not a good option, because of that fact that it duplicated the Array, which means that if you use it on big arrays it will eat enormous amount of memory, just to push a single item -> not good :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov - True for huge arrays `concat` may affect performance, but if using the `...rest` parameter it's safe to say that the intention is to add more than one item.  As always, it's a balance of code ease/maintainability versus performance needs.

Comment: I don't understand why someone might want to use `concat` instead of `push`? Push also adds more than one element :) http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#push()

Comment: @AndreyPopov - ...`push` is for adding one or more individual elements, `concat` is for combining arrays...so someone would use `concat` to...well...concatenate two arrays.  In the case of @idlackage's comment,  he is trying to combine two arrays (the `children` array and `...args` array).   It would have to be a pretty intense application for it to be noticeably more efficient to parse or apply the `...args` array instead of just using `concat`

Comment: Read the documentation carefully. Push takes **ARGUMENTS** and "Adds one **or more** elements to the end of an array". Concat **duplicates** the given array, so each time you use it with two arrays (new and old one to push into), it creates **third** array. I don't see how this can be good. Concat is used when you **don't want to modify** the original array :)

Answer (score 1):

When you do:  `var firstChild:Person = p.getChildren()[0]`  your not actually casting.  Your just trying to stuff an `Array` into an object you've defined as a `Person` and that's why you receive the error.

To cast, you need to do one of the following:

```
var firstChild:Person = Person(p.getChildren()[0]); //this will error if the cast fails

var firstChild:Person = p.getChildren()[0] as Person; //this will return null if the cast fails
```

A better approach however, may be to use a `Vector` - which in AS3 is like an array but all the members have to be of the specified type. So something like this:

```
private var children_:Vector.<Person>;
public function getChildren():Vector.<Person>{ return this.children_; }
```

Then you could just do:

```
var firstChild:Person = p.getChildren()[0]
```

Because each member of the Vector is already defined as a `Person` object.

---

Also,  you may want to consider using a getter method instead of `getChildren`.

```
public function get children():Vector.<Person> { return this.children_;}
```

Then you access it like a property (but can't set it).

Comment: For some reason I kept thinking that Vectors were unordered and thus never used them. Thanks for reinforming me otherwise.

Comment: All true, except the getter thing - it has no meaning to do so :) Good answer though.

Comment: No meaning to do so?  Not sure what you're saying.   I only suggest it because `p.children[0]` is more readable than `p.getChildren()[0]`.

Comment: I avoid giving such theories as it's all opinion based. It's best to use `p.getFirstChild()` ;) Anyways your answer is perfectly correct, I was just saying that the getter is not necessarily an advantage.